# Finding object position using calibrated camera and object size

Tags: coordinate-systems, projection, image-processing

I have a calibrated camera. In other words, I calculated the `extrinsic` and `intrinsic` parameters as below using opencv ([more info](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.15/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html)) (:

[image: camera projection formula]

The equation above maps real world coordination (`X`, `Y`, and `Z`) to image coordination (`u` and `v`).

Imagine the camera and the object as scene below:

[image]

where `P1` and `P2` are center of camera (calculated from camera calibration) and center of the object, respectively. `d` is distance between `P1` and `P2`. I can calculate `d` (using size of the object and focal length in a taken image, even in rotation). `w`, `h`, and `l` are `width`, `height` and `length` of the object, respectively and I know the value of them. `l` is very small and I show it for better illustration of 3d world (you can imagine the object as metal sheet).

As I read, by knowing depth information we can `go from 2D space to 3D space`. My question is that how can I calculate object coordination (determining `P2`) using aforementioned parameters in an image taken by the camera?

In other words, By supposing `d` as depth information and equation above (knowing `u`, `v`) how can I calculate coordination of `P2`?